# Why is a DG-enhancement of the derived bounded category of coherent sheaves an enhancement?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences, mirror-symmetry

In order to make mirror symmetry more compatible with homological machinery, I understand it is common to give the derived bounded category on a variety a "DG-enhancement" by keeping around the data of an affine Cech cover. This is the perspective taken in "Dirichlet Branes and Mirror Symmetry," section 8.2.1, page 586.

Fix an affine cover $\mathcal{U}$ on $X$ a nonsingular variety. The objects of $D^b_\infty(X)$ are bounded complexes of locally free sheaves (shouldn't this be coherent, not locally free?). We define for each $q$ a complex of degree-$d$ morphisms
$$
\mathcal{H}om^q(\mathcal{E}^\bullet, \mathcal{F}^\bullet) = \bigoplus_m \mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{E}^m, \mathcal{F}^{m+q}),
$$
(sheaf homs are over $\mathcal{O}_X$), which has a natural differential in increasing index. Combining this with the data of the Cech cover gives us a double complex, with Cech boundaries in one direction and the (degree-$q$ to degree-$(q+1)$) boundary in the other. We define the homset in our category to be the *total complex* of this double complex in the usual way:
$$
\operatorname{Hom}^n_{D^b_\infty(X)}(\mathcal{E}^\bullet, \mathcal{F}^\bullet) := \bigoplus_{p+q = n} \check{C}^p(\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{H}om^q(\mathcal{E}^\bullet, \mathcal{F}^\bullet))
$$

My question: the text asserts that if we take the cohomology of this category (i.e. cohomology of each its morphism complexes), we should recover the usual derived category $D^b(X)$. Is this obvious? There is an underlying spectral sequence computation, but I don't see why it simplifies.